# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '[...]\ReMod3D.exe'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

When I was using the Visual Studio 2010 and run my simulator, I got this error:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users[...]\ReMod3D\AIProject1World\ReMod3D.exe

The weird thing is that this error will disappear if I try to run it again after putting the VS2010 aside for a few minutes. I have checked the task manager and found no program like ReMod3D.exe  is running in the background when I got this error. Anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution! That is because my explorer is always locking the .exe file......the vs2010 cannot rebuild the .exe file because it's locked! The reason that the file is locked is  that I somehow disable my application experience service. I started it again and everything is fine now.